# How to post a multipart/form-data using a file from AWS S3

Tags: forms, amazon-s3, python-requests

I've an AWS Lambda function to post a form containing fields including a file from S3 to a HTML server.

```py
import requests
url = 'http://...'
# ...
self.session = requests.session()
# ...

filename = 'mammals/aboutzebras.doc'
data = {
    "name":"document",
    "method":"upload"
}

resource = boto3.resource('s3')        
objectSummary = resource.ObjectSummary('bucket', filename)
body = objectSummary.get()["Body"]
file_content = body.read()

files = {'file': ('content', file_content, 'application/doc;charset=utf8')}

page = self.session.post(
    url,
    files=files,
    data=data
    )

print("Status code = %s" % page.status_code)
# >> Status code = 500
```

I'm successfully getting the data from a MS-Word file from AWS S3 and putting it in `file_content` but do I need to base64 encode it? (I've tried w/o success).

On the request object sent by `requests.post` I can see in the headers `Content-Length` is set correctly, `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data` and that a `bounday` is set.

My call to `self.sessions.post` return a status code of 500 from the server I'm calling. What is my code missing?

If I submit to the `url` using a `<form>` in a HTML document then I get a `status_code` of `200` returned and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

A misunderstanding of the examples I followed:

```
files = {'file': ('content', file_content, 'application/doc;charset=utf8')}
```

The `'file'` position needs to the the form field name and not `'file'` and `'content'` is the file name and not the form field name.

e.g.,

```
files = {'fieldname': ('filename.ext', file_content, 'application/doc;charset=utf8')}
```