# Using aws s3 object as input to HTTP POST using python-requests

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-requests

I an API endpoint that accepts files as input. And I would like to use S3 files to be processed in that API endpoint.

Now doing it in my local file is pretty simple.

```
response = requests.post(url_endpoint, files={'files': open('myFile.pdf', 'rb')})
```

But when I do it in AWS Lambda using the S3 file, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
myFile = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketName, Key=fileKeyName)['Body'].read()

response = requests.post(url_endpoint, files={'files': myFile})
```

Boto3 get_object seems to be in a different format than `open('myFile.pdf', 'rb')`.
How do I get this to work?

Comment: Try using `.decode('utf-8`)` before sending it to the post request. The object coming out of your S3 Body is a byte stream, and it may be incompatible with requests.post.

Also, does your s3 bucket have any encryption on it? That could interfere as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here. [How to post a multipart/form-data using a file from AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164326/how-to-post-a-multipart-form-data-using-a-file-from-aws-s3)

Not sure where the documentation is, but this is what I did.

```
response = requests.post(url_endpoint, files={'files': (fileKeyName, myFile, 'application/doc;charset=utf8')})
```